# Printing a heap sort in reverse order if the priorities are the same

Tags: c, recursion, printf, priority-queue

I have a heap in C that is a priority queue. Currently, if I enter in 5 items of different priorities, it will print them based on their priority rankings. 5 being high priority, 1 being low priority, if I entered items like so (item name, priority):

item1, 1

item2, 2

item3, 3

item4, 4

item5, 5

It would print them back: item5, item4, item3, item2, item1

If they all had the same priority of 1 however, it prints them in as Last In First Out, and I would very much like them to print as First In First Out.

I created a print function and figure this can be done by recursion, but I'm having trouble getting the algorithm to work right. This is what I have:

```
int printOutput(queue_t *q, int count){
    int currentRank = get_rank(q); //Gets the top nodes rank value
    char* current = (char*)delete(q); //Gets the top nodes actual value
    if(count == 0){ //Base case, if the count goes down to 0
        return 1;
    }
    if(currentRank == get_rank(q)){ //If the current node's rank == next nodes rank
        printOutput(q, --count); //Recursively call this function, decrement count
        printf("Object Popped is: %s\n", current); //When that is done, print current
    }
    else{ //If the next ranking is not the same, just print current
        printf("Object Popped is: %s\n", current);
        printOutput(q,--count); //Recurse with lower count
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I enter 5 items with the same ranking value:

item1, 1

item2, 1

item3, 1

item4, 1

item5, 1

I would like them to print: item1, item2, item3, item4, item5

However they are printing: item1, item5, item4, item3, item2 with the code above

I am calling this function by passing in my priority queue and the count of nodes

printOutput(q, 5) for example.

Any way I could get this to work?

Comment: Seems to me that the priority should be handled as you add items to the queue.  Printing the queue should be as simple as pulling each item off the queue and printing it until the queue is empty.

Comment: Yeah, if the priorities differ, it works great. But if the priorities are the same, it prints Last In First Out (LIFO), where I would like to print items with the same priority as First In First Out (FIFO)

Comment: I think the problem is that the queue has been implemented as a stack, with push and pop operations, when in fact what you want to do is implement the queue as a FIFO with priority insertion.